# pull and update data to SAP business one using PHP

Tags: php, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

I want to integrate my php system with SAP business one to pull and update data such as customers, accounts, payments,..

I came through this following link but not sure where to download the api:
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7722?rid=/webcontent/uuid/df2bb865-0b01-0010-778f-cdf63a6c192a

I have also came through this (see correct answer) which suggests 3 ways of implementing this, but not sure how it works.
http://scn.sap.com/thread/855060

I am totally new to SAP, so please help me with suggestions on the best way to achieve this. 
Note: I dont have access to an SAP instance at the moment. Just doing initial explorations and getting ideas on the ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

To access the DI API installer, take a look at yor SAP Business One server (containing MSSQL, the license manager and the System Landscape Directory Tomcap application). It should export a SMB share named `B1_SHR` containing the DI API installer (usually located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\SAP Business One Server\B1_SHR`).

With the DI API installed, just create an instance of `632F4591-AA62-4219-8FB6-22BCF5F60090` (DI API 9.0 & 9.1; use `632F4591-AA62-4219-8FB6-22BCF5F60088` for DI-API 8.8) and use dynamic COM invocation to set properties like `Server` on the `Company` object before calling `Connect`.

Nevertheless I would recommend against using the DI API: it's horrible slow, needs a local installation on a Windows machine and a nightmare to debug. Just add an MSSQL server user with read-only access to the relevant tables in your company database (`OCRD` for business partners, `OACT` for general ledger accounts, `ORDR` for sales order documents) and query directly from PHP.

As soon as you run into a problem with the DI API, your SAP Business One partner will tell you to use the database anyway.